# Thingsboard - Authentication error on REST API (FROM Curl command and ASP.NET)

Tags: thingsboard

I'm able to login to Thingsboard website using my credentials, however when I try to connect the same using CURL command I get "Authentication Failed" error.

```
curl -X POST "https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/auth/login" -d "{"username":"XYZPQR@ABCDLMN.com", "password":"Q@34&pwn"}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json"
```

Error Code

```
{"status":401,"message":"Authentication failed","errorCode":10,"timestamp":1542893993515}
```

However when I use the same user id and Password in my ASP.NET Application to fetch the authorization token, I do get the JWT token, but using the same token I'm unable to make any REST API call from Thingsboard.

### ASP.NET CORE CODE

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
var client = new HttpClient();                
UserModel model = new UserModel { username = "XYZPQR@ABCDLMN.com", password = "Q@34&pwn" };
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

response = await client.PostAsync("https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/auth/login", content);

string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var userToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserToken>(data);

MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userToken.token);
Uri url = new Uri("https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/431be6e0-e8ca-11e8-9e5c-3d544ba4fdfc/values/timeseries?keys=Electricity");

response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

### Model Class

```
 public class UserModel {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserToken
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string refreshToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Please suggest, how to get the telemetry values from Thingsboard REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a small mistake I was doing; I changed old code to new code(as shown below), and everything started working as expected.

### Old code

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userToken.token);
```

### New Code

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization", "Bearer " + userToken.token);
```

Thanks for support.